# input() returns EOF Error while Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, eof

So I wanted to make my own Omegle interface in Python to get some practice with the language, and also it just sounded like fun. In order to handle the inputs and outputs at the same time, I've decided to use multithreading. This is my first time working with multithreading, so I don't really know what I am doing. Whenever I try and use input() while in a multithreaded function, it returns an EOF error. Any idea how to get around it, or if I'm going about this the entirely wrong way, what is a better way to do this?

Code:

```
from python_omegle import InterestsChat
from python_omegle import ChatEvent
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys



def start_chat_loop():
    interests = input("Please input interests: ").split
    chat = InterestsChat(interests)
    chat_loop(chat=chat)
    p2 = Process(target = take_input)
    p2.start()
    
def take_input():
    while True:
        i = input()
    
        if(i == "/next"):
            chat.disconnect()
        else:
            print("You: typing...")
            chat.send(i)
            print("You: "+i)

def chat_loop(chat):
    while True:
        # Start a new chat every time the old one ends
        print("- Starting chat -")
        chat.start()
        while True:
            event, argument = chat.get_event()
            if event == ChatEvent.CHAT_WAITING:
                print("- Waiting for a partner -")
            elif event == ChatEvent.CHAT_READY:
                common_interests = argument
                print("- Connected, common interests: {} -".format(*common_interests))
                break
        # Connected to a partner
        while True:
            event, argument = chat.get_event()
            if event == ChatEvent.GOT_SERVER_NOTICE:
                notice = argument
                print("- Server notice: {} -".format(notice))
            elif event == ChatEvent.PARTNER_STARTED_TYPING:
                print("- Partner started typing -")
            elif event == ChatEvent.PARTNER_STOPPED_TYPING:
                print("- Partner stopped typing -")
            elif event == ChatEvent.GOT_MESSAGE:
                message = argument
                print("Partner: {}".format(message))
            elif event == ChatEvent.CHAT_ENDED:
                print("- Chat ended -")
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = Process(target = start_chat_loop)
    p1.start()
```

Problem spots:

```
def start_chat_loop():
    interests = input("Please input interests: ").split
    chat = InterestsChat(interests)
    chat_loop(chat=chat)
    p2 = Process(target = take_input)
    p2.start()
    
def take_input():
    m = False
    while True:
        i = input()
    
        if(i == "/next"):
            chat.disconnect()
        else:
            print("You: typing...")
            caht.send(i)
            print("You: "+i)
```

Comment: You are not doing multi-threading, you are doing multi-processing. Processes have a much larger separation than threads. You can't simply use `input()` between them.

Answer (score 0):

Does your **chat.disconnect()** method have a way of escaping an endless loop? I'm not too advanced with this but I believe you should either do:

```
if(i == "/next"):
    chat.disconnect()
    break
```

or

```
def take_input():
    m = False
    while not m:
        i = input()
    
        if(i == "/next"):
            chat.disconnect()
            m = True
        else:
            print("You: typing...")
            chat.send(i)
            print("You: "+i)
```

I also noticed in the 2nd block of code that its written:

**caht.send(i)** instead of **chat.send(i)**. A syntax error might be preventing the loop of ending as well thus resulting in EOF.